# Backend Returns "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Header Twice, Each With Different Value

Tags: axios, http-headers, fastapi

I'm using Python's FastAPI to manage the server's API and Axios hooks on my Frontend.

Here's my code snippet that handles details of the CORS policy on the server:

```
origins = ["http://localhost:3000"]

 *****some code here*****

app = FastAPI(
        title=settings.PROJECT_NAME,
        version="1.0",
        docs_url=f"{settings.API_V1_STR}/docs",
        openapi_url=f"{settings.API_V1_STR}/openapi.json",
    )

app.container = app

app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

app.include_router(api_router, prefix=settings.API_V1_STR)
```

Here's the relevant hook that I'm using on the Frontend via Axios-hooks [axios-hooks docs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/):

```
const [
    {
        response: marketResponse,
        loading: marketLoading,
        error: marketError,
    },
] = useAxios({
    url: serverURL("market/list"),
    method: "GET",
});
```

It's important to note that I've double checked the allowed origin.

**The issue:**

As my web app requests the list via above mentioned axios hoook, the following error appears:

[Frontend HTTP Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFLFN.png)

Here's the Network Tab's Header Info:

[Network's Header Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddEhR.png)

As you'll notice Access-Control-Allow-Origin appears there 2x! Once in capped init letter and 2nd time in all lower case. I figured the issue somehow stems from this headers. Unfortunatelly can't find a particular way to fix it.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Googled multiple similiar issues and studied both Axios & Fast Api docs. Unfortunately couldn't find even a slight hint of solution.

Comment: Any chance you are using or just setting up another server in the part saying "some code here"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The issue

This is actually a known issue with the [Starlette CORSMiddleware](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/1309).
So the issue is that Starlette CORSMiddleware adds the origin header without checking if it already exists. That is by design.

FastAPI is wrapping this module.

If you take a look at the actual Starlette [code](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/048643adc21e75b668567fc6bcdd3650b89044ea/starlette/middleware/cors.py#L35) you will see that it is going to this [line](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/048643adc21e75b668567fc6bcdd3650b89044ea/starlette/middleware/cors.py#L58).

This explains the upper case version of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

#### So why is this happening?

Multiple servers are running. A known issue is if you are using `python-socketio` then the socketio will add its own version of the header.

I noticed this line:

`app.container = app`

What is the reason for this? Can you try to comment it out and rerun the code?

Else check if your NGINX is setting CORS.

Comment: Follow up,

The issue was resolved after you mentioned NGINX. Hold and behold, inside the nginx.conf file I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that produced the error. 

`app.container = app` has been produced via [Project Template Generation](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql) and I have to admit I don't know what purpose it serves.

Thank you!